How to underline text using `borb`
I am using the borb library, which has classes to represent textual content, such as ChunkOfText, LineOfText, HeterogeneousParagraph and Paragraph.
Although these have attributes (in their constructor) that enable me to choose the font, font size, color, etc, I did not find an attribute/method that would enable me to underline the text.
from borb.pdf import Document
from borb.pdf import Page
from borb.pdf import PageLayout
from borb.pdf import SingleColumnLayout
from borb.pdf import Paragraph
from borb.pdf import PDF

# empty document
doc: Document = Document()

# empty page
page: Page = Page()
doc.add_page(page)

# layout
layout: PageLayout = SingleColumnLayout(page)

# paragraph
layout.add(Paragraph("Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet"))

# store
with open("output.pdf", "wb") as pdf_file_handle:
   PDF.dumps(pdf_file_handle, doc)

Disclaimer: I am the author of borb.

The trick is to use ChunkOfText such that you can have layout information (the previous paint box) and then draw lines (using DisconnectedShape) for each underline.
import typing
from decimal import Decimal

from borb.pdf import Document, DisconnectedShape, PDF, Alignment, HexColor
from borb.pdf import Page
from borb.pdf import PageLayout
from borb.pdf import SingleColumnLayout
from borb.pdf import ChunkOfText
from borb.pdf import HeterogeneousParagraph
from borb.pdf.canvas.geometry.rectangle import Rectangle


def main():

    # create document
    doc: Document = Document()

    # create Page
    page: Page = Page()
    doc.add_page(page)

    # create PageLayout
    layout: PageLayout = SingleColumnLayout(page)

    # create ChunkOfText
    txt: str = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur nunc."

    chunksOfText: typing.List[ChunkOfText] = []
    for w in txt.split(" "):
        chunksOfText += [ChunkOfText(w)]
        chunksOfText += [ChunkOfText(" ")]
    chunksOfText = chunksOfText[:-1]

    # create HeterogeneousParagraph
    p: HeterogeneousParagraph = HeterogeneousParagraph(chunksOfText)
    layout.add(p)

    # underline some of the ChunkOfText objects
    for l in _lines_to_underline(p, [2, 3, 4, 8]):
        w: Decimal = abs(l[0][0] - l[1][1])
        DisconnectedShape(
            lines=[l],
            stroke_color=HexColor("f1cd2e"),
            vertical_alignment=Alignment.BOTTOM,
        ).paint(page, Rectangle(l[0][0], l[0][1], w, Decimal(2)))

    # build PDF
    with open("output.pdf", "wb") as pdf_file_handle:
        PDF.dumps(pdf_file_handle, doc)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()


Now let's look at _lines_to_underline, this method takes a HeterogeneousParagraph, looks at its individual content (LayoutElement objects) and attempts to build lines (represented as tuples of tuples of decimals). It also takes an argument idx representing the indices you want to be underlined.
def _lines_to_underline(
    p: HeterogeneousParagraph, idx: typing.List[int]
) -> typing.List[
    typing.Tuple[typing.Tuple[Decimal, Decimal], typing.Tuple[Decimal, Decimal]]
]:
    if len(idx) == 0:
        return []
    idx: typing.List[int] = sorted(idx)
    lines: typing.List[
        typing.Tuple[typing.Tuple[Decimal, Decimal], typing.Tuple[Decimal, Decimal]]
    ] = []
    for chunk_index in idx:
        c: ChunkOfText = p._chunks_of_text[chunk_index]
        r: Rectangle = c.get_previous_paint_box()
        # IF we are processing the first ChunkOfText
        # THEN we do not need to be concerned about potentially merging its coordinates with a previous ChunkOfText
        if len(lines) == 0:
            lines += [((r.get_x(), r.get_y()), (r.get_x() + r.get_width(), r.get_y()))]
            continue
        else:
            # IF the previously calculated line is drawn at (roughly) the same y-coordinate
            # THEN simply elongate that line
            y_delta: Decimal = abs(lines[-1][1][1] - r.get_y())
            x_delta: Decimal = abs(lines[-1][1][0] - r.get_x())
            if y_delta >= 5 or x_delta >= 5:
                lines += [
                    ((r.get_x(), r.get_y()), (r.get_x() + r.get_width(), r.get_y()))
                ]
            else:
                x0: Decimal = lines[-1][0][0]
                y0: Decimal = lines[-1][0][1]
                x1: Decimal = lines[-1][1][0]
                y1: Decimal = lines[-1][1][1]
                lines[-1] = (x0, y0), (r.get_x() + r.get_width(), y1)
    return lines

This method also does some first-attempt merging of lines, such that if two consequent words are underlined, only a single line is returned.
When we run this code, we get the following output:

